# Can i add website analytics to my custom CMS

Tags: php, html, web, statistics, analytics

I have built my own Content Management system for my sites, I want to add some "Website stats" (visitors etc) to it.

Is there a way I can do this?

I have tried Google Analytics but I want to show the graphs and charts in my cms and not in an external site.

Comment: You mention Google Analytics, but did you look at the [Analyics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/)? This would enable you to present the GA data directly within your CMS. (Look at the reporting APIs for more info.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google analytics have an api which can be used to generate your own stats.

Somes links :

- [Google Analytics API Launched!](http://analytics.blogspot.fr/2009/04/attention-developers-google-analytics.html)
- [Interesting post.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/google-analytics-api-and-php/)
- [Generate bar chart](http://www.standards-schmandards.com/exhibits/barchart/)
- [Generate bar chart2](http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/)